# File.Copy in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, file-copying

I'm trying to create a directory and copy a file (pdf) inside a `Parallel.ForEach`.

Below is a simple example:

```
    private static void CreateFolderAndCopyFile(int index)
    {
        const string sourcePdfPath = "c:\\testdata\\test.pdf";
        const string rootPath = "c:\\testdata";

        string folderDirName = string.Format("Data{0}", string.Format("{0:00000000}", index));

        string folderDirPath = rootPath + @"\" + folderDirName;

        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderDirPath);

        string desPdfPath = folderDirPath + @"\" + "test.pdf";

        File.Copy(sourcePdfPath, desPdfPath, true);

    }
```

The method above creates a new folder and copies the pdf file to a new folder.
It creates this dir tree:

```
TESTDATA
  -Data00000000
      -test.pdf
  -Data00000001
      -test.pdf
....
  -Data0000000N
      -test.pdf
```

I tried calling the `CreateFolderAndCopyFile` method in a `Parallel.ForEach` loop.

```
    private static void Func<T>(IEnumerable<T> docs)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(docs, doc =>
                                   {
                                       CreateFolderAndCopyFile(index);
                                       index++;
                                   });
    }
```

When I run this code it finishes with the following error:

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\testdata\Data00001102\test.pdf'
>   because it is being used by another process.

But first it created 1111 new folders and copied test.pdf about 1111 times before I got this error.

What caused this behaviour and how can it be resolved?

**EDITED:**

Code above was toy sample, sorry for hard coded strings
**Conclusion: Parallel method is slow.**

Tomorrow I try some methods from [How to write super-fast file-streaming code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955911/how-to-write-super-fast-file-streaming-code-in-c).

especially:  http://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/efficient-file-io-from-csharp/

Comment: As an aside, you should probably use `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating the path yourself.

Comment: @Mike I notice that you have not yet voted or accepted an answer on the site. May I suggest that you have a read of the [faq] to learn about these aspects of the Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are not synchronizing access to `index` and that means you have a race on it. That's why you have the error. For illustrative purposes, you can avoid the race and keep this particular design by using `Interlocked.Increment`.

```
private static void Func<T>(IEnumerable<T> docs)
{
    int index = -1;
    Parallel.ForEach(
        docs, doc =>
        {
            int nextIndex = Interlocked.Increment(index);
            CreateFolderAndCopyFile(nextIndex);
        }
    );
}
```

However, as others suggest, the alternative overload of [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359.aspx) that provides a loop index is clearly a cleaner solution to this particular problem.

But when you get it working you will find that copying files is IO bound rather than processor bound and I predict that the parallel code will be slower than the serial code.

Comment: This has to be the most overcomplicated foreach I have ever seen. Congratulations Parallels!

Comment: @BrianGraham A 2 line ForEach is complicated?

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I presume Brian is referring to the `index` handling

Comment: @AndrewFinnell `for (int i = 0; i < docs.Count; i++) CreateFolderAndCopyFile(i);` << alot less work than using parallels...

Comment: @BrianGraham Fine, but that's serial. And presumably Mike believes that a parallel algo will speed up the file copying.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan perhaps, but it looks sloppy to loop through a list and not even use what you loop through...

Comment: @BrianGraham You mean not using `doc`. Agreed that is odd. My guess is that Mike is just experimenting to get a feel for performance. Note the made up file names.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Thanks. I already up-voted your answer and gave a call out to that aspect in the penultimate paragraph in my answer. I've never used `Parallel`, and practically never use C# so I'm not familiar with exactly what's available in these libraries. Although I can spot an unsynchronized shared variable a mile off!!

Comment: You are right, paralel version is slower. What you suggest for fast file copy? Do you have any idea?

Comment: You won't do better than system provided file copy routines.

Comment: @all: Tomorrow I try some methods from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955911/how-to-write-super-fast-file-streaming-code-in-c. Maybe from this blog: http://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/efficient-file-io-from-csharp/

Answer (score 8):

Your increment operation on `index` is suspect in that it is not thread safe. If you change the operation to `Console.WriteLine("{0}", index++)` you will see this behavior.

Instead you could use a [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783359.aspx) overload with a loop index:

```
private static void Func<T>(IEnumerable<T> docs)
{
    // nb: index is 'long' not 'int'
    Parallel.ForEach(docs, (doc, state, index) =>
                            {
                                CreateFolderAndCopyFile(index);
                            });
}
```